# Are OpenCV matrix operations faster than simple for loop iterations?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, optimization

I want to understand if I should prefer to use the matrix operations defined for the cv::Mat class of OpenCV or if their computational time is the same of iterating with for loop on array of doubles.

Comment: Have you tried measuring it?

Comment: Actually I didn't I thought some one knew the answer without having to test them. So far I decided to implement the operation by myself, since were just vector/matrix multiplications.

Comment: Prewritten matrix libraries are usually optimized, and you will have a very hard time approaching the same level of performance.  If the native matrix operations map well onto the work you want to do, you have every reason to use them.  If they don't, what's the question?

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV cv::Mat classes use pointers in order to make them as efficient as possible. That being said, if you want to do a very specific manipulation you may find it quicker to implement yourself.

Below is the simple cv::Mat transpose code from the OpenCV Source Code:

```
void MatOp::transpose(const MatExpr& expr, MatExpr& res) const
{
Mat m;
expr.op->assign(expr, m);
MatOp_T::makeExpr(res, m, 1);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be CUDA code, what is its relation to the question?

Comment: changed the code, the point is OpenCV is optimised unless you have a very specific example